# How to fix 'Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.' error in Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures

While trying to call a stored procedure function in Laravel, I keep getting this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (SQL: exec TestProcedure(울산광역시, 남구, 신정동))

Note that in SSMS this stored procedure works fine when I pass the variables, which are, city, county, and address.

Here is my code in Laravel;

```
public function filterKoreanAddress(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $results = DB::select(
        'exec TestProcedure(?, ?, ?)',
        [
            $request->input('city'),
            $request->input('county'),
            $request->input('address'),
        ]
    );
    dd($results);
}
```

So, did I do anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Try to remove parenthesis -- `EXEC testprocedure ?, ?, ?`

Comment: Tried that but now i got this :/ `SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 65536. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. (SQL: exec TestProcedure 울산광역시, 남구, 신정동)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this

```
$results = DB::select(
    'exec TestProcedure(?, ?, ?)',
    array(
        $request->input('city'),
        $request->input('county'),
        $request->input('address'),
    )
);
```

Comment: but a slight modification that i made was by using @sticky bit's code mentioned above, where i removed the parenthesis'. so what i got was like ;
`public function filterKoreanAddress(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $results = DB::select(
            'exec TestProcedure ?, ?, ?',
            array(
                $request->input('city'),
                $request->input('county'),
                $request->input('address'),
            )
        );
        dd($results);
    }`